# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to the latest stable release?

Tags: installation, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I want to upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu. Is it possible? I read on this forum that I have to do a serial upgrading. If that is  the case, will all my software installed  previously be safe or do I have to reinstall them again? what happens to my data after upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu offers two upgrade paths. The first is **LTS->LTS** and the second being **stable release -> next stable release**. In your case, you are running Ubuntu 10.04 which is a Long Term Stable (LTS) release. So if you want to the upgrade to the latest stable release which is 13.10 (at the time of this answer), your upgrade path would be 10.04->12.04->13.04->13.10.

My recommendation would be to wait until April 17th 2014 or later at which point Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will be released. You can then easily upgrade to it by 10.04->12.04->14.04 which is much shorter.

*Note: Always backup your personal data before performing an upgrade. You will always reinstall all your application but personal data which is lost is lost forever.*

Comment: Hi Nik, thanks for the reply. I tried to upgrade first to 12.4LTS, it went fine initially, but in the later stages of installation, there were some jerks. It shows some files could not be installed but the installation continued (I dont remember the files exactly, it was something like ntfc..and etc.)Anyway, after installation, it prompted for restart. when I restarted, it could nolonger log into my ubuntu account. the boot is not even complete. it shows /tmp file not found. any help would be appreciated.....